# j_security_check dilemma - work around

Tags: security, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Before implementing j_security_check using MySQL realm authentication in my web app. I had the form info sent to a servlet (action controller) which would authenticate the user **and then add some info regarding the user to the session object**. Other servlets could then make use of this session object. After implementing j_security_check I dont know how to add the details of the login to the session object since j_security_check is being called instead of my controller and then it forwards to the requested page. Its like as soon as a user signs in - the data specified on the form is needed to create the session object , however i currently cant find any way of accessing the data submitted since its being passed to j_security_check. I tried using filters but i cant seem to read the submitted data directed towards j_security_check.Any suggestions on what i should do (I just want to set a session object as soon as a user signs in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information you can get in `j_security_chec`k is `username` and `password`. I don't see a use case of storing password in the session.

But, anytime the username can be obtained using `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()`